# Items per page in Kendo UI Grid

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-asp.net-mvc

I am using `Kendo UI MVC` and trying to have an option of showing all items in the grid.

```
var pageSizes = [{ text: "5", value: 5 }, { text: "10", value: 10 }, { text: "25", value: 25 },{ text: "All", value: rowCount }];

$('.k-pager-sizes select[data-role="dropdownlist"]').data('kendoDropDownList').setDataSource(new kendo.data.DataSource({ data: pageSizes }));
```

I was able to get all items displayed in a single page, but once I select 'All', The dropdown list item's text gets changed from 'All' to the value of rowCount.

I have tried changing the text in the databound event of the grid control but that doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Comment: I think there is a SelectedTemplate for drop down items. You can apply styling or text value overrides for the selected value. I've used it in the past. I'll try and find documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Found the documentation for the value template. You can apply that to your grid's dropdowns and customize the text for .

[Here is the documentation](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/template) for customizing the dropdown list.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I found a helper method that easily fixed the issue.

.Pageable(x => x.PageSizes(new List<object> { 10, 20, "all" }).Refresh(true))